# How do I display a form element only when a checkbox is selected?

Tags: forms, blocks

I want to create a form with a checkbox and two text fields. The text fields should only be shown when the checkbox is selected.

I am using this code.

```php
$form['display_count'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => t('Display count'),
  '#description' => t('Display how many times each term is used on a node.'),
  '#default_value' => $config['display_count'],
];

$form['count_prefix'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Count prefix'),
  '#description' => t('Set a prefix to be displayed before count number e.g. (5), [5] or <5>'),
  '#required' => FALSE,
  '#default_value' => $config['count_prefix'],
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      ':input[name="display_count"]' => [
        ['checked' => TRUE],
      ],
    ],
  ],
];

$form['count_suffix'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Count suffix'),
  '#description' => t('Set a suffix to be displayed after count number e.g. (5), [5] or <5>'),
  '#required' => FALSE,
  '#default_value' => $config['count_suffix'],
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      ':input[name="display_count"]' => [
        ['checked' => TRUE],
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Setting the #states value doesn't seem to work.

How do I display a form element only when a checkbox is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
$form['count_prefix'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Count prefix'),
  '#description' => t('Set a prefix to be displayed before count number e.g. (5), [5] or <5>'),
  '#required' => FALSE,
  '#default_value' => $config['count_prefix'],
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="display_count"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
    ),
  ),
];
$form['count_suffix'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Count suffix'),
  '#description' => t('Set a suffix to be displayed after count number e.g. (5), [5] or <5>'),
  '#required' => FALSE,
  '#default_value' => $config['count_suffix'],
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="display_count"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
    ),
  ),
];
```